# Python zeep - XML tag missing type declaration for string type

Tags: python, api, soap, zeep

When using zeep, the following code:

```
string_type = client.get_type("xsd:string")
string_expression = string_type("my string value")
```

Results in this:

```
<ns1:Value>my string value</ns1:Value>
```

What the serializer on the SOAP server expects is actually this:

```
<ns1:Value xsi:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">my string value</ns1:Value>
```

This discrepancy results in an Exception being thrown by the SOAP server:

> zeep.exceptions.Fault: The formatter threw an exception while trying
>   to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter http://Services.IPWS/. The
>   InnerException message was 'Element Value from namespace
>   http://schemas.datacontract.org/
>   cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use
>   XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

What could be done to get zeep to retain the type declaration in the XML tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to get zeep to generate the following tag, which is what the SOAP server expects:

```
value = zeep.xsd.AnyObject(zeep.xsd.String(), "my string value")
```

This results in:

```
<ns1:Value xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">my string value</ns1:Value>
```